# Parent/child pages and link structure the right way

Tags: links, child-pages

I've always wondered what's the best way to achieve the following with pages.

Say I have a (part of a menu) that looks like this:

**What we do**

- Design websites
- Develop websites
- SEO

The 'What we do' menu item is a custom one created with a # as link just to display the three sub items below on hover. It's not an actual page.

To achieve the desired link structure ( mywebsite.com/what-we-do/design-websites ) I would created an empty 'What we do' page, the parent, and the other three pages that are a child of the 'What we do' page.

The problem with this method is that the mywebsite.com/what-we-do link just shows an empty page. It's even worse when you're dispaying breadcrumbs on the site. It will show the parent page in the breadcrum with a clickable link but that just shows an empty page.

It's easier to solve with posts and using categories/taxomities as the 'What we do' part will be an archive showing all the related posts. But with pages? What's the best way to handle with this situation?